# Search for tags by their popularity

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-search

When I'm deciding what framework/library to use, I give a lot of weight to how many questions have been posted under their Stack Overflow tag. If, say, someone was looking for a new JavaScript physics engine, it would be really useful to be able to search for 'JavaScript physics engine' and have tags with matching descriptions returned by their popularity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) for this. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402952/finding-tag-by-excerpt-contents) is a query which lets you search in tag excerpts:

```
Select t.TagName, p.Body
From Tags t Inner Join Posts p On t.ExcerptPostId=p.Id
Where p.Body Like '%##contents##%'
Order By t.[Count] Desc
```

Note that SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, but for slow-changing content like tag descriptions this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

As a similar alternative to the answer; I wanted to see how how many views questions tagged with a particular tag are generating over time:

```
;with cte as (
  select
  FORMAT(convert(date, P.CreationDate), 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000') [date],
  P.ViewCount,
  P.Tags,
  P.AnswerCount

  from Posts P
  join PostTypes PT on PT.id = P.PostTypeId

  where
  PT.Name in ('Question')
  and Tags like '%<tag you want to see>%'
)

select
[date],
sum(ViewCount) ViewCount

from cte

group by
[date]

order by [date] desc
```