# Does the fact that SO questions tagged as GraphQL are receiving fewer and fewer views indicate that interest in this technology is dying out?

Tags: discussion

A question on this site - [Search for tags by their popularity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327419/search-for-tags-by-their-popularity) asks for searching for tags by popularity. From more experienced developers and SO users than I am... Is this a good means of assessing a technology's popularity?

What are the factors that an experienced developer would consider when assessing bias that assessing technology by popularity could introduce?

Specifically for my case. A query for the view count of questions with the `graphql` tag shows me that the number of views of GraphQL related questions has been steadily declining for over a year now.

Is it reasonable to correlate this with a decline in interest and adoption of GraphQL? It's an important consideration for me since I am tentative to introduce this technology to a project if it may lose community support.

This is the query:

```
;with gqlTags as (
  select
  FORMAT(convert(date, P.CreationDate), 'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000') [date],
  P.ViewCount,
  P.Tags,
  P.AnswerCount

  from Posts P
  join PostTypes PT on PT.id = P.PostTypeId

  where
  PT.Name in ('Question')
  and Tags like '%graphql%'
)

select
[date],
sum(ViewCount) ViewCount

from gqlTags

group by
[date]

order by [date] desc
```

[image]

Comment: A question is viewed when it is active (when it is asked, edited, answered, commented on) but over time it also generates views from visitors that find the question through Google or SO search. The amount of the first type of views may correlate with technology popularity, but the second type correlates with time, i.e., an older question has more time to collect views and therefore older questions on average have more views than newer questions. Your query does not seem to take this into account (i.e., you should divide view count by question 'age').

Comment: Ah - thank you. A friend also pointed me to the NPM download count: https://npm-stat.com/charts.html?package=graphql&from=2016-10-01&to=2019-07-30, which shows a steady uptake in GraphQL in terms of number of times it's downloaded. So in addition to taking @Marijn's division into consideration, then the difference in SO question view increase vs NPM downloads may indicate increase in GraphQL resources as alternatives to SO questions - i.e. an increasingly active community around the technology.

Comment: @Marijn " (i.e., you should divide view count by question 'age')" This would assume that interest in the question remained constant. But the hypothesis is here that interest in the field may have changed over time. We just don't have the time evolution of the views.

Comment: @Trilarion if [graphql] questions from 2015 have, let's say, 200 views per year on average, and questions from august 2018 have 100 views on average, wouldn't that imply that interest in the [graphql] tag (and it's questions) has decreased? Because if (average) interest in questions is constant then they both would be 200, if it is not constant then there must be a peak somewhere to increase the average of the earlier questions, and this peak would not be recent because then it would also affect newer questions, so the peak indicates interest that was there once but is now lost.

Comment: (assuming that intrinsic interestingness/usefulness of questions has not changed over the years, which may be a false assumption, in which case the reason for lower view counts is not interest in the technology but quality of the questions)